# Как подбирать параметры для функции поиска кругов методом Хафа в OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Доброго времени суток, стоит такая проблема: необходимо найти окружность на изображении, а точнее ее центр с точностью до четверти пикселя. Изменяя параметр "Разрешение аккумулятора" в функции cvHoughCircles я получаю координаты центра с дробной частью, но я до конца не понимаю как это работает и то ли я вообще делаю.
За что вообще отвечает этот параметр и как его подбирать?